# CRUD - using "call_user_func_array" to create new (php-activerecord)record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, phpactiverecord

I don't have an environment setup tonight to test this but this question has been nagging away at me all night so apologies.

I am using [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) within my codeigniter framework along with my attempted CRUD library.  I don't have a lot of experience with the function "call_user_func_array" - shame on me.  So I guess my question is... Will my expected result be the same as the actual result from this function

```
public static function create_record($obj, $attr){
     $ORM = new $obj;
     return (bool) call_user_func_array(array($ORM, "create"), $attr);
     //self::create_record('Object', array);
     //Expected:  (bool)Object::create($attr);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
CRUD::create_record('User', $this->input->post());
```

is like:

```
User::create($this->input->post());
```

Then just do the following, which is much simpler:

```
$obj = 'User';
$obj::create($this->input->post());
```

it also work if you are using namespaces.

```
$obj = 'app\models\User';
$obj::create($this->input->post());
```

Comment: That was my original approach, however I ran into some issue's with it somewhere down the line.  It works fine in the instance above.